# automatically jump back to content of page after submiting php form

Tags: php, html, submit, return

how can i make a php page with submit form and after submiting automatically returning to cast/content of page.

(BIG table with many rows)

Comment: Examples? Code? Show us what you've tried? And please rephrase the question, I can't understand where you're trying to go, and where did you come from.

Comment: Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq for more information on how to post on this forum.

Comment: I have database with one column and maybe 1400 rows in this table database. and with floating div on this php page i can add new row to database, and if i am in 546.row, so maybe in the middle of BIG page i add new word to database, so whole page is reloaded and i have to scroll down to 546.row(middle of BIG page) :/

Answer (score 2):

To go to a certain part of a page, you can use anchors. If your HTML elements have ID attributes, you can link to them using the hashtag (`#`). For example, if you have a table with rows:

```
<table>
    <tr id="row-1">...</tr>
    <tr id="row-2">...</tr>
    <tr id="row-3">...</tr>
</table>
```

You can link to row 2 by using `yourpage.html#row-2`.

In your PHP, you'll need to redirect with the correct row (you can redirect on the same page). You can use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to modify the HTTP header `Location` to cause the browser to redirect.

```
<?php
    $rowNumber = $_POST['row'];
    header("Location: form.php#row-$rowNumber "); //Same page as the page where this code is
    exit;
?>
```

Note that `header` needs to be used before any output is sent to the browser, and that the execution of the PHP will continue after the `header` call, so put an `exit` if you want to stop execution.

Comment: i have whole content in one page. for example page.php. :/ no two files. is it possible ?

Comment: @mayoxy it is not only possible, but it's also recomended to redirect to the same page to avoid re-submitting your form when you try to reload page just after submitting your form

Comment: @mayoxy yes, I had put that up because of I misunderstood your question. However, you will still need the redirection to change the URL to the right hashtag.

Comment: @Xeon06 ok, i understand your post, but how can i know on which hashtag i am in time when i submiting? i have only one form not 1400 forms. one floating form everytime on the center of page. even if i scrolling down

Comment: @mayoxy Oh I think I understand now, you just want to scroll back exactly to where you were before the submit? Your submit button like "stays with you" whenever you scroll and you want to go back to that position?

Comment: yes. yes. exactly what i mean !

Comment: @mayoxy In that case, I would look at Maerlyn's answer. I commented how to do it in PHP.

Comment: i think, if new row is added to database, content is changed ,because this new row is displayed in the table , which is actually the database. so, new <td></td> is added to table. hm.

Comment: @mayoxy Well, you should add your row using JavaScript and AJAX to do the database call if you don't want your page to refresh. Any other solutions will involve JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about browser support, but there's the 204 HTTP status, "No Content". The RFC states:

> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without causing a change to the user agent’s active document view, although any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document currently in the user agent’s active view.

This means that, if I have an HTML form and submit it, then, if the server returns a 204 status code, the browser should not refresh the form or take me to another page.

Comment: Wow that's pretty neat. [More info on this page.](http://benramsey.com/archives/http-status-204-no-content-and-205-reset-content/). To use in PHP, one could use `header('HTTP/1.1 204 No Content')`.

Answer (score 0):

Every row must have some uniq html `name` attribute and if you use this name after `#` sign in your url, browser will jump to its position.

Example:

```
<div name='item-256'>...</div>
```

and after submitting redirect to your page with big table using URL like `page.html#item-256`

Comment: ok, and how can php automatically know on which position on which item-xxx am i right now ?

Comment: If you have on every row new form, you can pass record id (e.g. the one used in database for the current record) to hidden element. In case you have one form for all rows, you can pass this value to some global hidden element via javascript, e.g. using onChange event on textfields.